Can I grant access to attributes of OpenLDAP's password policy?
Being asked to list users that have an expired or soon-to-expire password in OpenLDAP 2.4 (SLES12 SP5), I realized that only the admin user had access to essential attributes like pwdLastChange.
So I added a new special account that is to read those password policy (and shadow) attributes to fulfill the task.
After having set up the account and the access rights, I realized that the new account cannot access the attributes needed to fulfill the task.
Debugging access using slapacl, I saw the message

slap_str2ad(pwdLastChange) failed 17 (Undefined attribute type)

Does that mean it's a restriction of slapacl only, or does that mean it's impossible to grant access to those attributes?
Details
The command to check access was like

slapacl -v -d acl -D 'uid=PP-Checker,dc=..' -b 'uid=user-to-check,dc=...' "pwdLastChange/read"

and the essential part of the olcAccess was like

olcAccess: {2}to attrs=pwdAccountLockedTime,...,pwdChangedTime,...,shadowWarning by dn.exact="uid=PP-Checker,dc=...  read break

